# Thread 1: found nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This question might be a duplicate, but I think my case is different.

I built an app to fetch news articles from different sources. The problem I have is some sources may not include article image which causing my app to crash, please have a look at my code:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from url: String) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!) // I get Fatal error on this line
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error as Any)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

I tried to modify the code to not force unwrap the image if found nil, but It just didn't work, because I get other errors in other places.

If anyone can point the mistake, please, by writing how the code should be in case image found nil to not crash the app. It will be extremely appreciated!

Comment: you are trying to download image and set it async ?

Comment: Don't force unwrap and your problem will go away

Comment: @Ashley Mills Thank you for explanation! Remember that everyone was a beginner at some stage.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is force unwrapped. You should unwrap optional by using `guard let` construction:

```
guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to modify the code to not force unwrap the image if found nil,

Well yes it's duplicated question.

However this problem is solved by `OptionalChaining` i recommend reading about it [Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html),

Now for the part on how to solve it quickly, you can try to add this line under your request, which is going to check if its nil or not, and incase it was nil it will simply escape the closure without causing any crashes or problems.

```
guard let data = data else {return}
```

There are many types of `OptionalChaining`, each one has its own usage but they all serve the same propose of handling the `nil`  values without causing a crashes.

Answer (score -1):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    guard let data = data {

        self.image = UIImage(data: data)

    } else {

        print(value is nil.)

    }
}
```

- This is the way to safe unwrap the optional value. It will not crash if Data is nil on unwrapping .

Comment: add more details, and fix the answer format.

Comment: @Tobi I only suggesting optional chaining for unwrapping optional values. Please go through below link. [https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html]